# how do I convert my java files into an application?

Tags: java, executable, executable-jar

I coded up 4 .java files. The thing is that I can only execute my .java files from my IDE, how do I execute the .class files like an application? I study at uni, and I was told that Java is platform independent. Any tutorial/book recommendations would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is your IDE? Most of them have a "Run" button that allows you to run your program

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic idea (to give you some things to search for) is:

- Bundle your compiled .class files into a 'jar'.
- Add a manifest to your jar specifying a main class to run.

You might find your IDE already creates this when you run a 'clean build'.  Netbeans puts this into a 'dist' folder.

Modern JREs will allow you to run the jar by double clicking it etc.

You can also go a bit further by wrapping the jar in a native executable using a tool such as JSmooth.

Comment: +1 for pointing out native executable, and Netbeans jar creation.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [executable jar](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/). Here is the precise one, without any details, [Creating executable jar files](http://csdl.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/jar-files.html).

Answer (score 4):

What IDE are you using?

Depending on the IDE, some support [Export](http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/~dquigley/cse219/index.php?it=eclipse&tt=jar&pf=y) features that will create the .jar executable for you. For example, in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), you've got that option. Plus there are additional plug-ins for Eclipse, such as [Fat-Jar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/), that will include any additional libs you include that aren't part of Sun's standard libs.

Answer (score 3):

Java files have to run through the Java Virtual Machine, so you can run your class files from the command line.

If you have a file called *filename.java* you compile it to *filename.class* and then you can run it from a command line by typing *java filename*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to distribute your application on Windows, look into [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

JNLP/Web Start

Answer (score 1):

> "The basic idea (to give you some
>   things to search for) is:
>
> Bundle your compiled .class files into
>   a 'jar'.  Add a manifest to your jar
>   specifying a main class to run.  You
>   might find your IDE already creates
>   this when you run a 'clean build'.
>   Netbeans puts this into a 'dist'
>   folder." (by Cogsy)

Plus to achieve this you can either choose:

> Depending on the IDE, some support
>   Export features that will create the
>   .jar executable for you. For example,
>   in Eclipse, you've got that option.
>   Plus there are additional plug-ins for
>   Eclipse, such as Fat-Jar, that will
>   include any additional libs you
>   include that aren't part of Sun's
>   standard libs. (by kchau)

Or if you going to to serious stuff, opt for a build script like Ant or Maven. 
Here's an example of an Ant build.xml script:

```
<project name="jar with libs" default="compile and build" basedir=".">
    <!-- this is used at compile time -->
    <path id="example-classpath">
        <pathelement location="${root-dir}" />
        <fileset dir="D:/LIC/xalan-j_2_7_1" includes="*.jar" />
    </path>

    <target name="compile and build">
        <!-- deletes previously created jar -->
        <delete file="test.jar" />

        <!-- compile your code and drop .class into "bin" directory -->
        <javac srcdir="${basedir}" destdir="bin" debug="true" deprecation="on">
            <!-- this is telling the compiler where are the dependencies -->
            <classpath refid="example-classpath" />
        </javac>

        <!-- copy the JARs that you need to "bin" directory  -->
        <copy todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="D:/LIC/xalan-j_2_7_1" includes="*.jar" />
        </copy>

        <!-- creates your jar with the contents inside "bin" (now with your .class and .jar dependencies) -->
        <jar destfile="test.jar" basedir="bin" duplicate="preserve">
            <manifest>
                <!-- Who is building this jar? -->
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
                <!-- Information about the program itself -->
                <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="ACME inc." />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="GreatProduct" />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0.0beta2" />
                <!-- this tells which class should run when executing your jar -->
                <attribute name="Main-class" value="ApplyXPath" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get out of the IDE and familiarise yourself with the command line tools. The [java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) has a trail on the subject [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) (pick the Windows or Solaris/Linux section).